# Using a variable inside another

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to pass a value via PHP to a Javascript function but it isn't working, the value doesn't appear to be going through. When I replace the variable with static text, it works fine.

I'm calling the function via a PHP file like so..

```
<?php
if (!empty($data['geocode'])) {
    echo '<body onload="initializeGM(\'' . $data['geocode'] . '\');">';
} else {
    echo '<body>';
}
?>
```

`$data['geocode']` contains both the `lat` and `lng` as a string.

Here is the Javascript code..

```
function initializeGM(geocode) {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(geocode),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
```

I have added an `alert(geocode)` into the JS function to test and it works fine.

How can I make it so I can pass the `geocode` variable in and it works?

Comment: How are you passing the PHP variable to your function?

Comment: What does `$data['geocode']` typically look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, `geocode` is a PHP variable and you want to pass that into a JavaScript function call. If that's the case, you need to `echo` out the value of the PHP variable:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo($geocode); ?>);
```

**However**, note that the [`LatLng` constructor](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) expects 2 arguments of type Number (and an optional boolean argument), and you are only trying to pass in one argument. Although I may have completely misunderstood your intentions.

**Edit** (see comments)

I didn't notice that you were passing `geocode` as an argument to the `initializeGM` function. If you were actually trying to pass your PHP variable into that function you need to modify the call to the JavaScript function to use the PHP variable:

```
initializeGM(<?php echo($geocode); ?>);
```

The above "however" paragraph still applies though. Your code is likely to throw an error as `lng` will be `undefined` in the `LatLng` constructor function.

**Edit again** (see edited question)

What you have appears at first glance that it should result in something along these lines (as you've stated that `geocode` contains a string):

```
<body onload="initializeGM('somelat,somelng');">
```

There is nothing wrong with that in theory (a string will be passed into `initializeGM`) but the problem is that the function expects two arguments of type Number, not one argument of type String:

```
<body onload="initializeGM(100, 200);"> <!--Use real lat-lng values here!-->
```

That would require a change to the JavaScript function:

```
function initializeGM(lat, lng) { //2 arguments
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), //Pass 2 arguments to constructor
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
```

Comment: I think he's passing the PHP variable in the call to `initializeGM()`. Could be wrong though

Comment: Oh yeah, you may be right. Although to pass in a PHP variable to `initializeGM` he would need to modify the call to `initializeGM`, which has not been shown in the question.

Comment: @Brett - At first glance your code appears fine, but what you are doing seems to be the wrong approach. See my edit. If I'm wrong, post the generated HTML (view source in the browser and see what's actually been sent to the browser, rather than posting the PHP that generates the HTML).

Comment: Yeah... I realized not long after my last edit that I was posting the two arguments as one string. Not sure why I was doing that haha.... mustn't of been concentrating ;) Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`google.maps.LatLng`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#LatLng) constructor takes a minimum of two arguments, `lat:number` and `lng:number`. You are only passing one.

Assuming `$data['geocode']` looks something like `1.234,5.678`, try this...

1. Change your JS function to

   ```
   function initializeGM(lat, lng) {
     var myOptions = {
       zoom: 8,
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
   }
   ```
2. Change the call to

   ```
   <?php if (!empty($data['geocode'])) :
   $coords = explode(',', $data['geocode']);
   ?>
   <body onload="initializeGM(<?php printf('%.15f, %.15f', $coords[0], $coords[1]) ?>)">
   <?php else : ?>
   <body>
   <?php endif ?>
   ```